# Android Random Number

Tags: java, android

I m generating one random card from array. and assigning it.'
Below is the code..but its is showing an error.
What is the problem?

```
public void rand() {
    String rank[]=  {"tclub1.png", "tclub2.png", "tclub3.png", "tclub4.png", "tclub5.png", "tclub6.png", "tclub7.png", "tclub8.png", "tclub9.png", "tclub10.png","tclub11.png", "tclub12.png", "tclub13.png"};

    Random randInt = new Random();

    int b = randInt.nextInt((rank.length));
    showcard1.setBackgroundResource(b); 
}
```

Comment: Random.class error when i debugg.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the full error message? Where does it show up? In the log? Does the app itself just force close?

Comment: actually i m calling this method on my button click. and when i click it is force close my application

Comment: firstly tell my code above is correct or not?

Comment: @vivek_Android: Please post the error message, it will help us to give you the correct answer. Btw, showcard1 is not defined in your code, if you are looking for an error.

Answer (score 4):

b is an int

so you need rank[b] the array at some point in your code

According to your code maybe it should read
showcard1.setBackgroundResource(rank[b]);

Answer (score 3):

Try changing to `int b = randInt.nextInt((rank.length)) - 1;` (because rank.length = 13 and your array is indexed from 0 to 12)

Comment: `int b = randInt.nextInt(rank.length-1);` is slightly better ;-) (otherwise you *probabaly* get a -1 index)

Comment: I don't know Java, so I could be wrong here, but usually a rand(max) function will generate a number between 0 and max-1 already.  Otherwise, rand(10) could generate 11 possible values, which is almost never what you want.

Comment: Ed is right. Random.nextInt(n) - nextInt will generate values in this range [0, n> - This means that 0 is inclusive while n is exclusive. Therefore, by setting n to the length of the array, the generated values will not be out of the array's bounds. JavaDoc: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)