# Android Random resources

Tags: android, random

```
String rank[] = {"tclub1.png", "tclub2.png", "tclub3.png", "tclub4.png",
  "tclub5.png", "tclub6.png", "tclub7.png", "tclub8.png", "tclub9.png",
  "tclub10.png", "tclub11.png", "tclub12.png", "tclub13.png"};

Random randInt = new Random();
int b = randInt.nextInt(rank.length);
String d = ("tclub" + b + ".png");
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in value:=" + d);
```

Above is the code.
Actually my array is giving me one random index between(0 to 12)..after that I'm appending it to make an image name. eg(tclub1.png)
Now the image name which it gives to me is String format.
How can I assign this image now randomly?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315718/android-random-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the image to an ImageView, you can do this:

```
String imgName = "tclub1"; // the image you want to load
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: hi itsik..
thanks..but its not happening.
when i use log tag to see the value of ID it is showing 0
nd not setting the image randomly

Comment: Are all the images located in res/drawable? Also, the image name should be without ".png". (It should only be the resource name)

Comment: thanks a lotttttttttttttttttttttttt itsik..
its done with ur advice.
god bless u

Answer (score 0):

to find the control:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rockId);
```

To dynamicly load an image from drawable i use this helper function

```
public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)
{
    Assert.assertNotNull(context);
    Assert.assertNotNull(name);

    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

this will return the id of your drawable, now all you need to to is set the image in the control:

```
image.setImageResource(int Id);
```